# Twine is not asking for a password when I'm trying to publish my python library into Pypi

Tags: python, python-3.x, pypi, twine

I'm trying to upload my python library into PyPi.

I'm running this command:

`twine upload -r testpypi dist/*`

It asks for username and after I type it and press enter it is not asking for a password and just hangs.

[image]

Comment: please post the content of the image you had linked , instead of attaching a link to it ..

Comment: @Anti_cse51 I don't have Reputation 10, so I cannot post images yet. However there is nothing special in the image it just shows that `Enter password:` field is not appearing after I input my username.

Comment: Can you create an API token and use `__token__` as username? That might be an alternate approach

Comment: Um I think you problem here is that you don't have a test pypi account. You have a production pypi account.  Namely I can find you here: https://pypi.org/user/mzhadigerov/ but not here: https://test.pypi.org/user/mzhadigerov/

Comment: @Ali were you able to get it to work with my suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

This password hanging issue is likely due to a missing account on Test PyPI. Inspecting `pypi/user/<username>` I was able to find the user account: https://pypi.org/user/mzhadigerov/. However, on test-pypi, it's not available.

Note that these two PyPI services are different and you need to have separate accounts (preferably with the same user name for deployment simplicity)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem: twine asks for username, I type `__token__`, but then the "Enter your password:" prompt does not appear.

The issue was that I was running the command from Git Bash. It worked fine from the Windows Command Prompt.